# How to pass a file as hyperparameters for argparse

Tags: python, argparse

I am trying to reproduce a pipeline from github. Since the Idea is to reproduce it, I don't want to change the code. Onde of the scripts ask for hyperparameters to be passed as a dictionary, as in
 `-p {'param1' : 'p1', 'param1' : 'p2' ...}` and so forth. These parameters are processed with argparse.

I have a long list of parameters. Is it possible to pass the dictionary of hyperparameters as a file?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure it's a dictionary and not a JSON object that's supposed to be passed as a single argument? That seems like a very odd (and shell-unfriendly) argument format.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to modify the original script at all, you can create a wrapper script that reads the parameters from a JSON (let's call it params.json) and then calls the original script with these parameters.

```
{
  "param1": "p1",
  "param2": "p2"
}
```

and pass it using:

```
params=$(cat params.json)
python your_script.py -p "$params"
```

Answer (score 0):

`argparse` itself, by default, treats an argument starting with `@` as the name of a file from which it should read further arguments, one per line. So if you create a file named `args.txt` containing

```
-p
{'param1' : 'p1', 'param1' : 'p2' ...}
```

(assuming the "dictionary" is really supposed to be passed as a single argument) then

```
script.py @args.txt
```

should be equivalent to

```
script.py -p "{'param1': 'p1', 'param2': 'p2'}"
```

Comment: `@`  as `fromfile_prefix_chars` is common but not automatic.

Comment: It’s the default; you can adjust your usage based on what your parser defines.